# i m not able to see jat jar file

Tags: java, c, swing

i used see jar executable(java icon) f in my pc of all jar files. After formatting pc i have installed JDK and i`m not able jar file ie Java icon on that jar file it looks like winrar file how to see it as jar file .?

Comment: This question might be closed for being off topic. It probably belongs on http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[By default](http://www.rarlab.com/otherfmt.htm), Winrar will associate itself with `.jar` files. Open Winrar, find the filetype settings and un-check `.jar`. Windows should default back to opening with Java.

Comment: I have un-cheked .jar but its not showing java icon.

Comment: Is it just the icon that is wrong now? Does a `.jar` open with Java or WinRAR? You might need to reboot Windows in order for the icon cache to be reset.